# Anchor Layout places Widgets wrongly

Tags: android, python, kivy

I wanted to make an small program with one Label at the top, one Image in the Middle and another Label on the bottom.
I wanted to accomplish it with an AnchorLayout, but the Labels where placed in the Middle of the screen and the Image in the left bottom corner of the screen.
Why is this so?

Here is the kv file:

```
AnchorLayout:
    Label:
        text: k.l_text
        anchor_y: 'top'
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
    Knopf:
        id: k
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
    Label:
        text: k.t
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
```

Answer (score 0):

The AnchorLayout places all its children the same way according to its *own* anchor_x and anchor_y properties.

You would actually be better off with a FloatLayout, and using the pos_hint to set where the children are.

Comment: I alredy tried this, but when I typed in pos_hint: {"x": .5, 'y':.5} It did not placed the widget exactly in the middle, because it just placed the left upper corner of the middle.

Comment: That's because that *is* the pos_hint for placing the corner in the middle. Use center_x and center_y instead.